# Image animation delay issue in iPhone Safari

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css

I am struggling to figure out why the last image in the animation appears for its expected duration but does not fade back into img1 to start the animation again?  After img 12 the pause seems longer?

I have tested the animation in desktop: Safari, Firefox, Chrome, IE etc and works perfectly.  HOWEVER when it runs in iOS Safari on iPhone, I am experiencing this 'lag' between img 12 back to image 1?  So img 12 displays for its time as normal, but there is a blank pause for a second or so before the animation, and img 1 starts again?

I have the whole animation running for 48sec with each image at 4 seconds.  I think I've got the math right: 8.333% - 2% = 6.333%, 6.333% x 12= 76% therefore LESS than 100% total.

CSS:

```
  #crossfade > img {
  position: absolute;
  color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 48s linear infinite 0s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(1) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(2) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
  -o-animation-delay: 8s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
  -o-animation-delay: 16s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 16s;
  animation-delay: 16s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(6) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 20s;
  -o-animation-delay: 20s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 20s;
  animation-delay: 20s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(7) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(8) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 28s;
  -o-animation-delay: 28s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 28s;
  animation-delay: 28s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 28s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(9) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 32s;
  -o-animation-delay: 32s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 32s;
  animation-delay: 32s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(10) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
  -o-animation-delay: 36s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 36s;
  animation-delay: 36s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(11) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 40s;
  -o-animation-delay: 40s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 40s;
  animation-delay: 40s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 40s;
  }

  #crossfade > img:nth-child(12) {
  -moz-animation-delay: 44s;
  -o-animation-delay: 44s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 44s;
  animation-delay: 44s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 44s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  8.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  8.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  8.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  8.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  9% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  8.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  9% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  8.333% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="crossfade">
  <img src="fader/img1.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img2.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img3.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img4.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img5.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img6.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img7.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img8.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img9.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img10.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img11.jpg">
  <img src="fader/img12.jpg">
</div>
```